# Onepage checkout customer creation method

Tags: customer, onepage-checkout

I need to change default behavior of onepage checkout customer creation method, but i am unable to locate it.

All i found was method submitOrder Mage/Core/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php where i see:

```
        if ($quote->getCustomerId()) {
            $transaction->addObject($quote->getCustomer());
        }
```

Please help me to find where are magento receives user inputed form data from one page checkout, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic behind customer creation when placing an order can be found in the **_validateCustomerData** function of the **Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage** model.